# Case Object Not Updating with Logic When Another Object is Attached via Lookup

Tags: case, chat

I have a trigger in place that updates the case "Origin" field to a value of "Live Chat" once that case has been attached to a transcript via a Lookup Field. My test class does not seem to be working for me as it tells me my assert is not working

```
@isTest
public class LiveChatOriginUpdate_Test {
static testMethod void TestChatTranscript (){

    Test.startTest();

    LiveChatVisitor testVisitor = new LiveChatVisitor();
    insert testVisitor;

    Case testCase = new Case(Origin = 'Not Live Chat');        
    insert testCase;

    LiveChatTranscript testTranscript = new LiveChatTranscript(LiveChatVisitorId = testVisitor.Id, Case = testCase);
    insert testTranscript;        

    update testCase;


    system.assertEquals(testCase.Origin, 'Live Chat');

    Test.stopTest();      

}


}
```

The problem that I am running into is that the expected (first value in the assert statement) is still listed as "Not Live Chat." I am trying to find a way to see if this is because the change to the live chat transcript is not indexed yet when I go to do the assert. I would appreciate any tips you could throw my way, thanks.

Below is the code making the update.

```
   trigger LiveChatOriginUpdate on LiveChatTranscript (after update) {

List<Case> ChatCases = new List<Case>();


for (LiveChatTranscript transcript : Trigger.new) {

    if (transcript.CaseId != null) {

        Case caseToUpdate = new Case(Id = transcript.CaseId, Origin = 'Live Chat');


        ChatCases.add(caseToUpdate);
    }

}

// update the list if there are records to be processed
if (ChatCases.size() > 0) {
    update ChatCases; 
}
```

}

Comment: Can you include the code that is supposed to be making this update?

Comment: updated to include trigger code

Answer (score 0):

The reason will be because you're not checking the values in the database, you're checking the values in the locally held variable.  To check the updated value, you'll need to query the database.

i.e.

```
@isTest
public class LiveChatOriginUpdate_Test {
    static testMethod void TestChatTranscript (){

        Test.startTest();

        LiveChatVisitor testVisitor = new LiveChatVisitor();
        insert testVisitor;

        Case testCase = new Case(Origin = 'Not Live Chat');
        insert testCase;

        LiveChatTranscript testTranscript = new LiveChatTranscript(LiveChatVisitorId = testVisitor.Id, Case = testCase);
        insert testTranscript;

        Test.stopTest();

        // Query the database for the new value

        testCase = [SELECT Id, Origin FROM Case WHERE Id = :testCase.ID][0];

        system.assertEquals(testCase.Origin, 'Live Chat');

    }
}
```

I'm assuming your `LiveChatTranscript` constructor associates the case with the transcript.

Comment: I appreciate your input, unfortunately this did not resolve the error. This is a good step in the right path to start digging.

Comment: Does the LiveChatTranscript constructor update the case?  Otherwise you'll need to udpate the case with the livechattranscript.  I'm not sure of the syntax for that.  What field relates a Case to a LiveChatTranscript?

Comment: The field is on the Chat transcript object and the lookup field is named case. You attach a case to a transcript rather than the other way around. According the logic in the trigger, the origin should update when that case is associated with a transcript.

Comment: aaah, lightbulb moment.  You're associating the LiveChatTranscript to the Case in an insert, but your trigger runs on update.  add in a 'after insert' to the trigger.

Comment: Logically this would make sense but the test still did not pass. Nor did it pass when seealldata=true

Comment: Is it working via the UI but not in the test?  One thing I did notice was the extra `update testCase;` line after the `insert testTranscript;` line.  If you haven't removed this, it will overwrite the value set in your trigger.